# PHPUnit Selenium2 calling a function

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, phpunit

I am testing with PHPUnit and Selenium2. I am testing the admin panel. So, I need to add `Admin Login Test` into all my admin panel tests.

I want to create a new `Admin Login Test` with a new file and I want to call this function from all my tests. How I can create and call my `Admin Login Test` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create function AdminLogin

   1. Create into each test class method SetUp ([doc](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/fixtures.html))
   2. Call admin_login by SetUp

Looks like:

```
protected function setUp()
{
    AdminLogin();
}
```

This method calls before each test into test class

Good luck!

Comment: But I want to create AdminLogin function into new file and I want to reuse like require_once function. It is possible?

Comment: If i understand correctly than yes.
You can call method from another class in php. Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503734/php-calling-another-class-method

Comment: Using setup is way for calling methods before each tests.